# How can I prevent reloading the page when we go back to the previous page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing, ionic3

Now I am working with Ionic3, Angular4 android app. It is reloading the page  in android app every time when i am going back to the previous page. How can prevent this. Still that page is already loaded. SO I don't want to reload again and again

Comment: show us some code. what do you mean by reloading?

Answer (score 0):

Use Push and Pop in ionic framework  which works as a simple stack that new pages are pushed onto and popped off of, corresponding to moving forward and backward in history.

[Refer Ionic documentation too](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation)

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <button (click)="goToOtherPage()">
      Go to OtherPage
    </button>
  </ion-content>`
})
export class StartPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  goToOtherPage() {
    //push another page onto the history stack
    //causing the nav controller to animate the new page in
    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Other Page</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>I'm the other page!</ion-content>`
})
class OtherPage {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.navCtrl.push(Page);` instead of `this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page);` and remember to do

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.viewCtrl.showBackButton(true)
}

goBackToPreviousPage() {
  this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```